# Dependent type constraints in generic class with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, generics

How can I create a generic with two parameter where the second parameter is dependent on the first. In this case I'm creating a hash class, where I need both the type of the object and the key that identifies it.

Some simplified code for explanation:

```
class MyCache<T,Key> : where T is CommonImpl {
   Dictionary<Key,T> cache;

   T Get( Key v ) {
      ...
      var newValue = new T(v);
      return newValue;
   }
}

class ImplA : CommonImpl {
   public ImplA( String key ) { }
}

class ImplB : CommonImpl {
   public ImplB( SomeType key ) { }
}
```

Where I have two uses of this cache `MyCache<ImplA,String>` and `MyCache<ImplB,SomeType>`.

Comment: What is `Value`, and how can it be `ImplA` and `ImplB` at the same time?

Comment: Sorry, I had changed the name of the parameter. I fixed the code now.

Comment: Still, the second question remains.

Comment: I want to say it can be one of those two types. I'm not clear on the syntax for that.

Comment: Then you would need a common base class.

Comment: There is no way to limit `T` to 2 specific unrelated classes. You would have to make them both either inherit from a base class or implement an interface and then restrict `T` to the base class or interface.

Comment: Let's assume they share a base class (code updated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve is something like this:

```
public abstract class Base<TKey>
{
    public Base(TKey key) { }
}

public class ImplA : Base<string>
{
    public ImplA(string key) : base(key) {}
}

public class MyCache<TBase, TKey> where TBase : Base<TKey>
{
    public TBase Get(TKey key)
    {
        return (TBase)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TBase), key);
    }
}
```

You can then call

```
var b = new MyCache<ImplA, string>().Get("hi");
```

Comment: Okay, this part I have now, but how do I get the constraint on the `Key` parameter? Or do I even need one?

Comment: Not quite, I actually need to get a new instance of `ImplA` or `ImplB`, and I need to store that object.  But maybe this could work if I extend IDoer.

Comment: I was unable to find a way to do the object constrution.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: It works with the `new()` constraint. Can you update your sample with your current code and exact problem?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y I think now I figured out what you're trying to achieve. See edit.

Comment: I've not tested this yet, but it looks like what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't say to a generic class / method it should be Concrete `A` or `B`. You can only tell it it has a common denominator: a base class or an interface.

This is how it should look for example:

Interface:

```
interface IImpl {
    void SomeCommonMethod();
}
```

Generic class (here you tell `T` must implement the interface, so it can be any class that implements the interface). Also you have to tell it has a default constructor using the `new` constraint (as noted in comments, it is not possible to tell it has a parameter with type `Key`):

```
class MyCache<T,Key> : where T : IImpl, new()  {
```

Key classes:

```
class ImplA : IImpl {
   public ImplA( String key ) { }
}

class ImplB : IImpl {
   public ImplB( SomeType key ) { }
}
```

Comment: Okay, this part I have now, but how do I get the constraint on the `Key` parameter? Or do I even need one?

Comment: What do you expect `T` to be?

Comment: You can only have a type constraint on a parameterless constructor, `new()` is valid, `new(key)` is not.

Comment: @BenRobinson: That is a pity, but you are right. Updated.